# static assertion failed: tuple index must be in range

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to modify the code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828683/c-stdget-equivalent-with-run-time-arguments) by returning the tuple index value instead of printing. The code in the link allows passing runtime integer to `std::get<>` on `std::tuple`. After modifying the code I'm getting `index out of range` error. My Compiler supports only `C++11`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Tuple>
std::tuple_element<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value, Tuple> get_impl(size_t i, Tuple const& t, typename std::tuple_size<Tuple>::type) {}

template<size_t N, typename Tuple, typename = std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value != N>>
std::tuple_element<N, Tuple> get_impl(size_t i, Tuple const& t, std::integral_constant<size_t, N>)
{
    if(i == N)
    {
        // std::cout<<std::get<N>(t)<<std::endl;
        return std::get<N>(t);
    }
    else
    {
        return get_impl(i, t, std::integral_constant<size_t, N+1>());
    }
}

template<typename Tuple>
std::tuple_element<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value, Tuple> get(size_t i, Tuple const& t)
{
    return get_impl(i, t, std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>());
}


int main() {
    std::tuple<int, double, std::string> t(7, 9.8, "text");
    int idx = 0;
    std::cout << get(idx, t) << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

https://godbolt.org/z/xYTrbM69E

Comment: Think about how this is supposed to work: you have a runtime value `i` that the compiler cannot know in advance. How should it know when to stop instantiating versions of `get_impl` with an ever-increasing `std::integral_constant<size_t, N+1>()`?

Comment: You can't write a function that returns different types depending on a runtime value, so there is little point in trying.

Comment: I believe the compilation errors are caused by the return type for `get` being the type "one past" the last tuple element and thus something that does not exist. (In this particular case, it is `std::tuple_element<3, std::tuple<int, double, std::string>>`, and the valid indices are 0, 1, and 2.)

Comment: Both branches should be valid, even if not taken.

Comment: `std::tuple_element<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value, Tuple>` This is obviously wrong; just as wrong as say `int x[3]; x[3] = 42;` Just as there's no element `x[size]` in an array of size `size`, there's no element in a tuple at index `std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>`